# Realm migration, where to initialise

Tags: ios, swift2, realm, realm-migration

I'm trying to work with one of the documented methods of migrating a realm database and setting the schema version. The kind of code I am using is:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
    // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
    schemaVersion: 1,

    // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
    // a schema version lower than the one set above
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
            // Nothing to do!
            // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
            // And will update the schema on disk automatically
        }
})

// Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

This seems to be pretty standard code, and looks to be used by others. However, what seems to be tripping me up is where I am initialising the Realm instance which is causing the schema setting not to set or persist.

what I am struggling with is where to set the following code:

```
let uiRealm = try! Realm()
```

- If I put this at the top of AppDelegate above @UIApplicationMain it initialises too early
- If I create a controller file, that I intend to call a function within after the migration, and put the initialiser at the top of that it still doesn't work
- If I put it within the class of a ViewController as in the code below I get the error Instance member uiRealm cannot be used on type XYZViewController

  ```
  import UIKit
  import RealmSwift

  class XYZViewController: UITableViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {

      let uiRealm = try! Realm()
      var scenarios = uiRealm.objects(Scenario).filter("isActive = true ")

  }
  ```

So my question is: are there any best practices on where to initialise, and how best to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you've set your `Configuration` object as your Realm's default configuration before any other parts of your code call `Realm()`.

Best practice is to not hold onto any references to `Realm()` unless you have a very good reason. Each time you call `Realm()`, it will return a previously cached instance of the object, so there are no performance benefits by creating a reference to an instance, and then hanging onto that one for the lifecycle of your app.

The best place for setting your `Configuration` object with the migration information is as soon as possible, before the code has had a chance to call `Realm()`. So the app delegate is a good place for this.

If you've got class properties that are relying on `Realm()` already being preconfigured, it might help to prepend the `lazy` keyword to those properties so their creation is delayed until you actually need them.

Comment: Thanks for this, so how do I convert the following into a lazy initialisation? scenarios = uiRealm.objects(Scenario).filter("isActive = true "). If I just put lazy in the front I get the error "Use of unresolved identifier uiRealm"

Comment: No worries! Hmm, is there any reason why you can't just use `Realm()` instead of uiRealm?

Comment: Hi, I got round this by declaring var scenarios: Results<Scenario>! at the top and then initialising the realm within each function. Again I was trying to do too much as a global eatable and have moved everything into functions.

Comment: Moreover. Adding the following code gets us the lazy version of the initialiser  lazy var uiRealm:Realm = {
  return try! Realm()
 }()